# Website development on multiple machines

Tags: macos, npm, mamp-pro

I'm searching for a best practice when I develop website projects locally on more than one machine. I use a small CMS and Node for the development.

Is it possible to work on a external SSD?

Comment: What does an external drive have to do with this?  Sure, it's possible to save files on an external drive.  That's exactly what an external drive does.  (Or an internal drive.  Or any drive.  Or any storage device.)  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry. Probably I was not that specific. I meant it that way:  I develop the websites in my office on one machine. And sometimes I have to work on the same project at home. I'm not sure, if there could be problems with Mamp, the Node-Stuff etc.

Comment: Do you not use a source control system?  You really should.  Even if you're the only developer, even if you only ever develop on a single machine, even if you develop only very simple projects... use source control.  Take a look at GitHub, or any similar available tool.  (You could even run your own source control server, but that's overkill given the services available for free.)